# How to restart level upon collision in Corona sdk

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, game-development

I'm trying to get the level to reload itself upon detecting a collision with the player. The player is listed as a "dynamic" physics body, and the objects that its reacting with are labeled as "kinematic". How do I get the level to reset itself upon detecting a player collision with any object? Here is my code:

```
local function onGlobalCollision( event )
    if ( event.phase == "began" ) then
        composer.gotoScene("level1")
    end

    player.collision = onGlobalCollision
    player:addEventListener ("collision", player)
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you remove all event listeners, sceneGroups, stop physics and remove the scene in your scene:hide method. Upon starting up again it should restart everything. Also, I don't think you do not need the if(event.phase...).
Your code should be:

local function onGlobalCollision( event )

```
composer.gotoScene("level1")

player.collision = onGlobalCollision
player:addEventListener ("collision", player)
```

end

Hopefully that will work for you.